# Laravel: Sort Table Joined Using 'With' Clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 4 and Eloquent ORM. I'm currently pulling records from my database using the following code:

```
public function index($type, $id)
{               
    $asset = Asset::where('public_id', '=', $id)
            ->with('attachments')
            ->with('attachments.attachment')
            ->with('tracks')
            ->with('tracks.track')
            ->where('locale', '=', Config::get('app.locale'))
            ->first();

    return View::make('view-asset.index')
            ->with('asset', $asset)
            ->with('type', $type);
}
```

The table joined to this query using the `with('tracks')` statement has a column in it called `track_order` - I would like to be able to sort the rows returned by this part of the query by that column so that the tracks stored in the database are returned in the correct order.

Is it possible to do this and if so, how should I do it? So far I've tried something like this:

```
public function index($type, $id)
{               
    $asset = Asset::where('public_id', '=', $id)
            ->with('attachments')
            ->with('attachments.attachment')
            ->with('tracks')
            ->with('tracks.track')
            ->where('locale', '=', Config::get('app.locale'))
            ->orderBy('tracks.track_order', 'ASC')
            ->first();

    return View::make('view-asset.index')
            ->with('asset', $asset)
            ->with('type', $type);
}
```

Which doesn't work and I can't figure out a way of doing this other than splitting things up into multiple queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most certainly can:

```
with(['tracks' => function($query)
{
    $query->orderBy('track_order', 'asc');
}])
```

Refer to [Eager Loading Contraints](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) in the documentation for more.